# Adding update to a app (Phonegap)

Tags: cordova, ota

I have built an App using Phonegap.The App contains three icons on the home screen.For specific users i would like to roll an update which adds one more icon without disturbing other content.This icon gives them permission  to edit content published others.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to roll updates for different users try giving the app a list of urls of the phonegap pages and then try packing them into zip or tar ball and roll as an update.On the device try to extract them and link to existing application.Hope it solves your problem.